Strange problems with navigation mixin behavior for the CDN domain deployed
We are using third-party package which has the following code inside which defines URL link for uset to click
if (this.isSalesforceLink) {
  this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
    type: 'standard__recordPage',
    attributes: {
      recordId: this.recordIdAttribute,
      actionName: 'view',
    },
  }).then((url) => {
    this.salesforceRecordUrl = url;
  });

We didn't change or override this code but the way how it behaves is non deterministic.
Sometimes it provides correct URL link like following
https://customer.domain.com/expsite/s/article/Test-Article
but sometimes the wrong URL like
https://customer.domain.com/expsite/s/?redirectPageContext='BASE64ENCODED-URLENCODED-navigation-mixin-link' which is not opened and user is redirected to login page even if the user is already logged in.
If we decode the Base64 string and the url-decode we could see the following
{
  "type": "standard__recordPage",
  "attributes": {
    "recordId": "ka0Dy0000009qj0IAA",
    "actionName": "view"
  },
  "state": {
    
  }
}

We have verified that the both guest and experience cloud users have access to the knowledge article record and it is published and available for Experience Cloud site and to the public knowledge.
Why different URLs are generated by the NavigationMixin?
How can we prevent this from happening?
